# Authenticate Powershell script on SharePoint site using Claims

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, powershell, powershell-2.0, claims

I have the following problem:

my team uses a SharePoint team site, for delivering our work among other things. We are SharePoint developers and write a lot of powershell, but as far as this site is concerned, we are mere users, not admins. We wrote scripts that upload and download documents to and from the site. Here's a simple example of what we did:

```
$Credentials =  Get-Credential

​....

Download-File -Url $fileUrl -Destination $Destination -Credentials $Credentials
```

The Get-Credential function causes the username/password dialog to pop up. This worked until the provider of the site change the method of authentication to Claims. Now we get a 403:

**"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."**

I've been googling this for some time, I got a lot of articles on how to set up Claims authentication on a SharePoint web application. But this was all admin stuff, which is of no use to me, as I don't have the necessary permissions on the site. What I need is an example of how to use it. How to authenticate using Claims from powershell. Because providing credentials gained via Get-Credential is clearly no longer enough.

Additional info: I'm using correct credentials, they work when I try to log on to the site manually via a browser. I also have full rights for the file I'm trying to access. We're using Powershell version 2, developing for SharePoint 2010. The site I'm trying to authenticate for is (most likely) SharePoint 2010 too.
Thank you in advance.